# How to calculate distance traveled by vehicles using distanceByRoute with AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I'm working on a model which is similar to Product Delivery model in Anylogic where there's a population of retailers and warehouses and for each demand, the vehicles of warehouses make the delivery. I want to calculate the distance traveled by vehicles to make delivery and to calculate the cost of transport. I used DistanceByRoute method in the state. However it didn't work. However after simulation it tells me that there's an error
That's the code that I put in the entry action in the state "Unloading":

`FuelCost = (DistanceCalcule / 100) * ConsoFuelPerKM*(FuelPrice)  + FuelCost; 
DistanceCalcule=(order.retailer.distanceByRoute(vehicle))*2;
DistanceParcourue = DistanceParcourue + DistanceCalcule;`

However after simulation it tells me that there's an error

[This image in this link shows the states that i've used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Zfq.png)

[this image in this link shows what I put in the state Unloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKF5d.png)

Comment: You don't say what "it didn't work" means. What outcome were you expecting and what did you get? Also, what error did you get and how did you only get an error "after simulation"? (Did you run the experiment despite there being an error identified during the model build?)

Comment: When I write codes in the state "unloading" in order to calculate the traveled distance and then the fuel cost, I get error after simulation, I didn't understand why it didn't work ! the pictures below (in the answer below) show where I wrote the code and what happened after simulation

Answer (score 0):

So the error did occur *during* the run (and such errors --- Java exceptions --- always stop the run).

The Console messages allow you to click the blue text to go to the offending lines of code. It being a `NullPointerException` most likely means (from what you posted) that your `warehouse` variable was null when you tried to call `distanceByRoute` on it.

Why this happened depends on the rest of your model logic.

Comment: Plus much better to edit your question to include the new detail, rather than posting a spurious answer.